# PayPal sandbox UK Payments Pro Hosted payment page does not process card

Tags: paypal

We are trying to integrate PayPal’s UK Payments Pro with the hosted payment page.

We have created a new sandbox UK business account and a UK customer account.

Each time we attempt to make a payment, we get this error:

> This transaction can't be processed. Please pay with another card.

Here is the HTML for our POST:

```
<iframe name="hss_iframe" width="570px" height="540px"></iframe>
<form style="display:none" target="hss_iframe" name="form_iframe" id="form_iframe" method="post" action="https://securepayments.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/HostedSoleSolutionApp/webflow/sparta/hostedSoleSolutionProcess">
<input type="hidden" name="buyer_email" value="nata@print-science.com">
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="dulger">
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="nata">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://xyzprinting.he18.printscience.net/paypalprohostedipn">
<input type="hidden" name="subtotal" value="21.03">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://xyzprinting.he18.printscience.net/paypal_cancel_2014?order=325558RL">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://xyzprinting.he18.printscience.net/paypal_successful">
<input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale" />
<input type="hidden" name="template" value="templateD" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="ps-uk@printscience.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_hosted-payment" />
<input type="hidden" name="address1" value="123 Cheapside">
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="London">
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="London">
<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="EC2 R 8AH">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="325558RL">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.form_iframe.submit();
</script>
```

Comment: This really is the sort of thing you should bring up with PayPal's technical support people.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the business value to the Secure Merchant ID value that is specified at the top of the Profile page of the Sandbox Test Site. The field should contain something like:

name="business" value="HNZ3QZMCPBAAA"

See the developer guide, p.64: https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_GB/developer/docs/pdf/hostedsolution_uk.pdf